# Broken Saddle Tee In Irrigation System

Tags: irrigation, sprinkler-system

I notice a broken line in my yard and when I dug the line up I have a white tee connector. Looking online it looks like a Poly Pipe Kwikseal Saddle Tee. The nut is missing, which I assume has caused the leak. I am wondering what the best fix would be. Should I replace it with the same tee or is there another way? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image: What I Can Replace With?]

Answer (score 1):

I can see no one answered this and though I'm not a pro but after experiencing the same exact issue this week and doing internet research and asking staff at 3 different irrigation specialty supply stores, the common answer was: No, a new 100C Dawn Kwikseal saddle tee cannot be used to replace it because it won't have the same perfect seal as the original saddle tee install because of how the seal is done when the original hole in the poly pipe is made while the original saddle tee is clamped on.  They stated that eventually it will leak and promote more root growth from the nearby tree roots. Plus, those saddle tee's will have the same failure flaw in a few years if roots grow around it breaking the nylon bolt. They all recommend cutting the pipe at or around the perforation point and using an inserted T fitting with hose clamps on either end to provide a better water tight seal.  They also said you could try using the newer Kwik Tap poly saddle that has a pointed insert tube that goes into the existing hole but it may eventually leak as well.  bottom line is it's more work but the better longer lasting option is to cut the poly pipe and use a T coupler insert with clamps.